# Segmentation fault when using malloc for 2D array

Tags: c

I create a 2-D array using `malloc`. When I use `printf` to print the array element in for loop, everything is fine. But when I want to use `printf` in main, these is a `Segmentation fault: 11.`

Could you please tell me what the problem with the following code is?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void initCache(int **cache, int s, int E){
int i, j;
/* allocate memory to cache */
cache = (int **)malloc(s * sizeof(int *)); //set 
for (i = 0; i < s; i++){
    cache[i] = (int *)malloc(E * sizeof(int)); //int

    for(j = 0; j < E; j++){
        cache[i][j]  = i + j;   
        printf("%d\n", cache[i][j]);
    }
  }
}


main()
{
    int **c;

    initCache (c, 2, 2);

    printf("%d\n", c[1][1]);  // <<<<<<<<<< here

}
```

Comment: you changed the local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed a local variable, which won't effect the local variable `c` in main.

If you want to allocate in the function, why pass a variable? Return it from the function.

```
int **c = initCache(2, 2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since your cache is a 2D array, it's `int**`. To set it in a function, pass `int***`, not `int**`. Otherwise, changes to `cache` made inside `initCache` have no effect on the value of `c` from `main()`.

```
void initCache(int ***cache, int s, int E) {
    int i, j;
    /* allocate memory to cache */
    *cache = (int **)malloc(s * sizeof(int *)); //set 
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        (*cache)[i] = (int *)malloc(E * sizeof(int)); //int
        for(j = 0; j < E; j++){
            (*cache)[i][j]  = i + j;   
            printf("%d\n", (*cache)[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
initCache (&c, 2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `return`, or else a `***` as suggested by others.  I'll describe the `return` method here.

`initCache` is creating and initializing a suitable array, but it is not returning it.  `cache` is a local variable pointing to the data.  There are two ways to make this information available to the calling function.  Either `return` it, or pass in an `int***` and use that to record the pointer value.

I suggest this:

```
int** initCache(int **cache, int s, int E){
   ....
   return cache;
}


main()
{
   int **c;
   c = initCache (2, 2);
   printf("%d\n", c[1][1]);   <<<<<<<<<< here
}
```

====

Finally, it's very important to get in the habit of checking for errors.  For example, `malloc` will return `NULL` if it has run out of memory.  Also, you might accidentally as for a negative amount of memory (if `s` is negative).  Therefore I would do:

```
cache = (int **)malloc(s * sizeof(int *));
assert(cache);
```

This will end the program if the malloc fails, and tell you what line has failed.  Some people (including me!) would disapprove slightly of using `assert` like this.  But we'd all agree it's better than having no error checking whatsoever!

You might need to `#include <assert.h>` to make this work.